# Netlogo behaviorspace, How to export each experiment's plot in a separate directory with a unique name? (Answer is by using pathdir extension)

Tags: netlogo

I have a save-plots function which I call it in my final command of behavior space to export selected plots, I could create unique names for plots so they don't replace each other, for example my output file name for one of the plots is like this:

DeathRates, PS true,  HCHA false  100,true.csv

```
Let FileNameDeathRates ( word "D: /Results/" "DeathRates, "  "PS  "PS? ",  HCHA " HCHA? MPS "," CV? ".csv" )
```

So far is good, but I want is to have a directory with name of the experiment and export all plots of that experiment in that directory for example:

```
Let DirName( word "D:/Results/"   "PS  "PS? ",  HCHA " HCHA? MPS "," CV? )
```

Netlogo already exports plots with proper name and I just want the directory name to be different , and of course prior to the experiment the directory does not exist so the directory should be created first , I could not find a command to create a directory in netlogo without pathdir extension.

Any idea on how can I do this?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that NetLogo doesn't offer a way to create a directory without using the pathdir extension.